# Is Cassandra / ScyllaDB capable of handling millions of very wide data rows?

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql, storage, scylla

A new business need has emerged in our firm, where a relatively "big" data set needs to be accessed by online processes (with typical latency of up to 1 second). There is only one key with a high granularity / rows count measured in tens of millions and the expected number of columns / fields / value columns will likely exceed hundreds of thousands.

The key column is shared among all value columns, so key-value storage, while scalable, seems rather wasteful here. Is there any hope for using Cassandra / ScyllaDB (to which we gradually narrowed down our search) for such a wide data set, while ideally reducing also data storage needs by half (by storing the common key only once)?

Comment: redesign the database, split the tables, in many ideally following some rules the joins them

Comment: I cannot redesign it - business users could but would rather not... But I did narrow down the question to Cassandra/ScyllaDB (to address the closing voter's concern of an opinion poll).

Comment: every database has limits, as the width of a table makes the handling much more complicates and resource consuming. As for humans can't handle in the most  part that many columns, to figure out logic. so use the uuid or what ever you have as joing column for new tables that expand the first too big table.

Comment: It probably could be implemented in a relational database, I agree, but imagine the complexity... for efficiency reasons each such smaller table would have to be kept below 500 columns, which requires that the data maintainers split these 100k dictionaries into at least 200 tables...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your use case correctly, your use case will have tens of millions of **partitions** (what you called rows), and each will have hundreds of thousands of different values in each of them (each those would be a **clustering row** in modern CQL - CQL no longer supports un-schema-ed wide rows). This is a fairly reasonable data set for Scylla and Cassandra.

But I want to add that I'm not sure the storage saving you are hoping for will really be there. Yes, Scylla/Cassandra will not need to store the partition key multiple times, but unless the partition key is very long, this will be often be negligible compared to the other overheads of storing the data on disk.

Another thing you should consider is your expected queries. How will you read from this database? If you'll want to read all 100,000 columns of a particular key, or a contiguous range of them, then the data model you described is perfect. However, if the expected use case is that you always plan to read a *single* column from a specific key, then this data model will be inefficient - a random-access read from the middle of a long partition is slower than reading the value from a short partition.

Comment: The use case is de facto an online Feature Store. We already have one, properly implemented with Redis, but here Redis would take too much memory, because the keys here have to be as long as the range of unique IDs (no aggregation is permitted). I know it is very strange to use unique IDs in a Feature Store, but it is for cross-sell purposes, to transfer precise (non-aggregated) per-customer features from most data-rich products to the data-poor ones.

Comment: Yes, queries efficiency is a very valid consideration. This is why MinIO was ruled out (tests made without any concurrency show that 100k sequential reads would take 1h  instead of < 1s). But just like in our existing Redis-based Feature Store, also in this case the incoming requests will contain all necessary lookup keys (here: only one - the unique customer ID) that will allow for querying for all 100k values at once (assuming we manage to represent this amount of data properly).

Comment: @nadav-harel : after a successful PoC I've just posed a follow-up question regarding optimal data structure, which you may also find of some interest : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73015140/how-to-redesign-this-classic-table-to-scale-it-from-3-to-300k-columns-in-cassand

Comment: As for queries efficiency, I've just verified in comprehensive tests that if your timeout budget is 1 second, then Cassandra scales to *hundreds of thousands* of (integer) columns (sharing the same key), all put into the same wide table, regardless of the number of partitions / rows - at least up to 1 mil. rows. In fact it was the data loading times (from CSV files) that turned out to be the bottleneck here... dsbulk takes tens of hours to load 10k (2-column) CSV files with 1 mil. rows.

Comment: It shouldn't take "tens of hours" to upload 10 gigabytes of data (if I understand your numbers correctly). I don't know if "dsbulk" (with which I'm not familiar) is very slow, or it's Cassandra which is very slow (I prefer the much faster Scylla, but full disclosure - I'm a Scylla developer).