# How to redesign this classic table to scale it from 3 to 300k columns in Cassandra / Scylla?

Tags: database, optimization, cassandra, nosql, scylla

***Background***. As part of our new online Feature Store we are trying to store hundreds of thousands of dictionaries (value columns with a common key) in Cassandra or Scylla. Each column (array of numerical values) shares the same key, but the key has 10's of millions of values.

As a ***proof of concept*** I've created a classic relational structure with just 3 columns:

```
cassandra@cqlsh> use dicts;

cassandra@cqlsh:dicts> create table dict7 (my_id bigint primary key, claims_count1 int, claims_count2 int, claims_count3 int);

cassandra@cqlsh:dicts> select * from dicts.dict7 limit 10;

 my_id | claims_count1 | claims_count2 | claims_count3
-------+---------------+---------------+---------------
```

I then used the `dsbulk` to import the data in bulk from 3 different CSV files (all sharing the same key column) into a familiar tabular structure (it scaled linearly within this range of columns):

```
$ dsbulk load -url '/bitnami/' -k dicts -t dict7 -m '0=my_id,1=claims_count1,1=claims_count2,1=claims_count3' -header true 
[..]
    total | failed |  rows/s | p50ms | p99ms | p999ms | batches
3,000,000 |      0 | 138,713 |  1.16 |  5.28 |  47.97 |    1.00
Operation LOAD_20220717-182904-961642 completed successfully in 21 seconds.

# verify the shape of the table after bulk import with dsbulk
cassandra@cqlsh> select * from dicts.dict7 limit 10;

 my_id       | claims_count1 | claims_count2 | claims_count3
-------------+---------------+---------------+---------------
 83169182337 |             8 |             8 |             8
 93720935273 |            14 |            14 |            14
 22123160926 |            14 |            14 |            14
 59858873056 |             2 |             2 |             2
 15189958258 |             1 |             1 |             1
 62520394543 |             0 |             0 |             0
 76981665176 |            17 |            17 |            17
 65124136708 |            11 |            11 |            11
 94816325274 |            10 |            10 |            10
 33337620895 |            14 |            14 |            14
```

***At inference time*** (in production) the client app making the requests (with a timeout of 1 second) will need values from all columns at once for one of the existing keys:

```
cassandra@cqlsh> select * from dicts.dict7 where my_id=22123160926;

 my_id       | claims_count1 | claims_count2 | claims_count3
-------------+---------------+---------------+---------------
 22123160926 |            14 |            14 |            14
```

***The question*** is how to redesign this classic structure to make best use of Cassandra data models in order to scale it efficiently from these 3 to 300k columns?

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something, your use case is **exactly** what Cassandra/Scylla's "clustering key" is for!

Your schema is

```
   my_id bigint primary key,
   claims_count1 int,
   claims_count2 int,
   claims_count3 int,
```

You can replace is with

```
   my_id bigint,
   claims_id int,
   claims_count int,
   primary key (my_id, claims_id)
```

What this says is that `my_id` is a **partition key** and `claims_id` is a **clustering key**. For each value of `my_id` you have a partition (a wide row) which includes many clustering rows - each clustering row has a clustering key (`claims_id`) and a value (`claims_count`). You can have 300k of these claims - just instead of calling them claim_count1, ... claim_count300000 they will each be a `claim_count` value belonging to a different `claim_id`.

More concretely, if you want to set claims_count7 to 54, you'd do something like:

```
UPDATE tbl SET claims_count = 54 WHERE my_id = ... AND claims_id = 7
```

Now you can easily and **efficiently** query all the clustering rows (i.e., all claims_id,claims_count pairs) of the same partition with exactly the same command you used:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE my_id = ...
```

This SELECT is efficient, because Scylla keeps the partition contiguous and sorted (by the clustering key).

Comment: This schema seems so scalable! The variables are more heterogenous though, so column clusters will be smaller, not spanning all 300k features (I should not have given such a special case with sequentially numbered columns, apologies). On the other hand, features naming is far from randomly uniform, we even see some very large clusters of features, with thousands of columns:)

Comment: The feature name (the "clustering key") does not need to be an integer. It can be a string if you want. It also doesn't need to be sequential - Scylla/Cassandra will keep the list of clustering rows in each partition _sorted_, but it doesn't need to be contiguous clustering key. When you read the partition, you'll get everything sorted by clustering key.

Comment: Excellent. But I wonder what performance hits would we incur during the planned row-wise queries if we don't / can't use the clustering key(s)? FWIK in my classic schema the data would be represented / stored as nested JSONs, where first-level keys are rows, here: {row1: {"my_id": 83169182337, "claims_count1":"8", "claims_count2":"8", "claims_count3":"8"}, row2: {"my_id": 93720935273, "claims_count1":"14", "claims_count2":"14", "claims_count3":"14"}, ...} so the entire row data would be already stored together, and fast to retrieve?

Comment: Is the name "row1" important? In my suggestion, the partition key would be `my_id`, and you can query the entire row just by querying `WHERE my_id = ...` - this will efficiently get you all the claims counts of this `my_id` because they are indeed all stored together.
You should install Scylla and just try it :-) (Cassandra and DynamoDB have the same partition/clustering key design, so you can try any of them with the same data model).

Comment: Good news! We will try to scale the PoC up to more columns then, relying on that row-wise storage and quickness of retrieval using partitioning key. The only software-imposed limitation I know of is 2 billion cells in a partition (here: row), which is rather unlikely to be hit in your line of business:) BTW that row1 object in my comment was just some internal/private row ID/name that C*/Scylla probably uses(?)

Comment: The biggest obstacle to trying out either Cassandra or Scylla inside our company is currently security... lack of containers that would meet our corporate security requirements (mostly hard ones) (i.e. 1) rootless, 2) with dynamically changeable user IDs, 3) based on a system without high vulnerabilities. Each of the currently available containers of C*/Scylla fails on 1 or 2 of these counts. But for Scylla I must also add an entirely new unmet condition: 4) based on a system stable enough for production (it's currently using Fedora).

Comment: The containers / security thing is a separate issue. If you're considering the open-source Scylla, you can ask these questions on the scylladb-dev@googlegroups.com mailing list, or if you're considering a commercial license, contact Scylladb officially. I don't think you're the first Scylla (and definitely not Cassandra) user with strict security needs. And of course you can also test this on your laptop before going all corporate, just to see it makes sense for you.

Comment: Agreed, let's not pile up any more issues here:) But unbeknownst to the OSS community most corporate clients have to customize most open-source containers to solve the above issues.... We are conducting the PoC simply under docker on a realistic but still non-production (isolated) server in the cloud. OK, I will raise the above issues on Scylla's Github (ref. to https://github.com/scylladb/scylla/blob/master/tools/toolchain/Dockerfile).